# Accessing variables inside a model passed to live data

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-livedata

in User repository, I am fetching the data from the database and I cast into the model class User.

How do I access two variables user and email of the model class inside the live data?

ViewModel

```
class MyViewModel (private val repository: UsrRepository) : ViewModel() {

private var cUser : LiveData<User> = repository.getCacheUser()

val user: LiveData<String> = cUser.user
val email: LiveData<String> = cUser.email

}
```

Xml

```
<TextView
            android:text="@{viewmodel.user}"

<TextView
            android:text="@{viewmodel.email}"
```

Comment: Have you tried `val user = cUser.map { it.user }` using `lifecycle-ktx`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not doing any transformations on the data provided by `cUser`, you can just make it public in your ViewModel:

```
val cUser: LiveData<User> = repository.getCacheUser()
```

Then access the user properties from the LiveData directly in the layout:

```
android:text="@{viewmodel.cUser.user}"
android:text="@{viewmodel.cUser.email}"
```

If you did not want to use the raw values, and instead some other computed values, you would instead expose a [transformation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#transform_livedata) of `cUser`, creating a new LiveData that has values modified from the original.